# JEE can't run JAX-RS WebService skeleton app

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Windows, NetBeans 8.0.2, GlassFish 4.1. I can't make my example JAX-RS app running.

This is pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.wld</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWebService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HelloWebService</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>HelloWebService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

and web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.wld.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my console output:

```
NetBeans: Deploying on GlassFish Server 4.1
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Starting GlassFish Server 4.1
GlassFish Server 4.1 is running.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Learning\HelloWebService\target\HelloWebService
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
cd C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Learning\HelloWebService; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_31" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dnetbeans.deploy=true -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Users\\tomasz.ducin\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\8.0.2\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 package\""
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building HelloWebService 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ HelloWebService ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 0 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ HelloWebService ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ HelloWebService ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Learning\HelloWebService\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HelloWebService ---
No sources to compile

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ HelloWebService ---
Surefire report directory: C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Learning\HelloWebService\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


--- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ HelloWebService ---
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [HelloWebService] in [C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Learning\HelloWebService\target\HelloWebService]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Learning\HelloWebService\src\main\webapp]
Webapp assembled in [60 msecs]
Building war: C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Learning\HelloWebService\target\HelloWebService.war
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3.109s
Finished at: Sat May 30 14:53:50 CEST 2015
Final Memory: 11M/245M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
NetBeans: Deploying on GlassFish Server 4.1
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Learning\HelloWebService\target\HelloWebService
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
```

As you can see, there is only one java file. No resources, no tests, no test resources. Anyway, GLassFish fails to serve the app. I've been looking in the web, but can't find the reason. I'm thinking about some Windows-related things, such as ports, firewalls or any other OS stuff.

Below is glassfish console output:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
maj 30, 2015 2:53:34 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
maj 30, 2015 2:53:34 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
maj 30, 2015 2:53:34 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@d21e255 in service registry.
Found populator: com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\GF_4.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 312ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 10ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (2 138ms), startup services(1 647ms), total(3 785ms)
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 26ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@109d724c as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@4ba89729.
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://WAWLT548.global.ad:8686/jndi/rmi://WAWLT548.global.ad:8686/jmxrmi
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 13ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Java security manager is disabled.
Info:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Info:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Info:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Info:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Info:   Created virtual server server
Info:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Info:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Info:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Warning:   Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /C:/Users/tomasz.ducin/Learning/HelloWebService/target/HelloWebService/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.
Info:   Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.wld.rest
Info:   Root resource classes found:
  class com.wld.rest.HelloService
Info:   No provider classes found.
Info:   Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'
Severe:   WebModule[/HelloWebService]StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Unable to create resource
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.SingletonFactory$Singleton.init(SingletonFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:584)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    [...]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.SingletonFactory$Singleton.init(SingletonFactory.java:137)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResponse(WadlBuilder.java:395)
    [...]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.getApplication(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.<init>(WadlResource.java:77)
    ... 81 more

Severe:   WebModule[/HelloWebService]Servlet /HelloWebService threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResponse(WadlBuilder.java:395)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Startup of context /HelloWebService failed due to previous errors
Severe:   ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5954)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5946)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResponse(WadlBuilder.java:395)
    [...]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5704)
    ... 50 more

Warning:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /HelloWebService
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Warning:   Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /C:/Users/tomasz.ducin/Learning/HelloWebService/target/HelloWebService/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.
Info:   Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.wld.rest
Info:   Root resource classes found:
  class com.wld.rest.HelloService
Info:   No provider classes found.
Info:   Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'
Severe:   WebModule[/HelloWebService]StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Unable to create resource
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.SingletonFactory$Singleton.init(SingletonFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:584)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.SingletonFactory$Singleton.init(SingletonFactory.java:137)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResponse(WadlBuilder.java:395)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateMethod(WadlBuilder.java:164)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResource(WadlBuilder.java:331)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResource(WadlBuilder.java:269)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generate(WadlBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.getApplication(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.<init>(WadlResource.java:77)
    ... 81 more

Severe:   WebModule[/HelloWebService]Servlet /HelloWebService threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResponse(WadlBuilder.java:395)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Startup of context /HelloWebService failed due to previous errors
Severe:   ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5954)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5946)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResponse(WadlBuilder.java:395)
    [...]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5704)
    ... 50 more

Warning:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    [...]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /HelloWebService
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
```

I've tried cleaning, building, building with deps, restarting the IDE several times with no effect. Don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glassfish 4 uses Jersey 2.x. You should change the dependency and web.xml configuration accordingly. For the dependency, you can use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And configuration

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.wld.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

One "gotcha" a see a lot of people (who are using Glassfish and Jersey) lately is the fact that Glassfish uses an older version of Jersey (old in the sense of an older 2.x version). The latest as of now is 2.17. Glassfish uses something near the first one in the 2.x family. So there seems to be some compatibility problems with new features.

One thing I would definitely look into is [Updating Jersey 2 in GlassFish 4](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/21/updating-jersey-2-in-glassfish-4/). It's a pretty good article. You may not face any issues will simple startup apps, but with new features, trying to upgrade Jersey in Glassfish might help.

Another thing, remember to get rid of your Jersey 1.x dependencies. The two are completely incompatible. Also notice the `provided` scope in the Maven dependency. Since Glassfish has Jersey built in already, we are just using the internal dependencies.

Also a good thing to keep handy is the [Jersey 2.x Documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)

Oh and one other thing. Jersey has an archetype that helps you get started easily. In Netbeans just do

1. New Project
2. Maven → Project from Archetype
3. Search `jersey-quickstart-webapp`
4. Select the one with the Group ID `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes`
5. The latest version should be displayed.

Comment: The `jersey-quickstart-webapp` archetype is especially useful. I'm a newbie in configuring jersey with JAX-RS, so I think it's way better to use an archetype rather than fight with configuration. Thanks!