# How to run jersey-server webservice server without using tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jersey

This is my first time dealing with web-services. Simply, I need to send a post request from jersey web service client (inside a webpage implemented in javascript) to a jersey service which is in one of my maven modules.

As I said I've created jersey-server within one of my maven modules and I would like to run it somehow (I do not know how to run a web service program.) before starting client side of my implementation. Through searching on the web, I saw lots of examples but all of them was using tomcat. So my first question is that do I need to use tomcat (or something like this ) in order to run a web service ? Secondly, below I shared my jersey-server module. How could I start to run it ?

```
package com.exampleProject.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.List;


@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SiderRecommender {

    @POST
    @Path("/functiontest")
    public List<Recommendation> sampleFunction() {
        // return something here. I removed it for simplicity.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the client application also a part of your Jersey project/application?

Comment: @peekskillet no, I mean if you're asking whether client app is in the same maven module, it is not. I've implemented server side by using java and jersey. Now, I'll implement client app in some javascript file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't *have* to run a Jersey app in an installed web server. You can run it in an *embedded* server, meaning a server that runs in standalone mode with a normal `main` method.

If you are using Maven, and you are familiar with creating Maven archetypes, you can use the `jersey-quickstart-grizzly2` archetype

- [From Command line](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-from-archetype)
- [From Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30020830/2587435) (except use `jersey-quickstart-grizzly2`)
- [From Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30546891/2587435) (See bottom of answer. Also use `jersey-quickstart-grizzly2`).

This is everything you get for free with the archetype project.

[image]

`Main.java`

```
package com.underdog.jersey.grizzly;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

/**
 * Main class.
 *
 */
public class Main {
    // Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";

    /**
     * Starts Grizzly HTTP server exposing JAX-RS resources defined in this application.
     * @return Grizzly HTTP server.
     */
    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
        // in com.underdog.jersey.grizzly package
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.underdog.jersey.grizzly");

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

`MyResource.java`

```
package com.underdog.jersey.grizzly;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

`MyResourceTest.java`

```
package com.underdog.jersey.grizzly;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MyResourceTest {

    private HttpServer server;
    private WebTarget target;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // start the server
        server = Main.startServer();
        // create the client
        Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        // uncomment the following line if you want to enable
        // support for JSON in the client (you also have to uncomment
        // dependency on jersey-media-json module in pom.xml and Main.startServer())
        // --
        // c.configuration().enable(new org.glassfish.jersey.media.json.JsonJaxbFeature());

        target = c.target(Main.BASE_URI);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        server.stop();
    }

    /**
     * Test to see that the message "Got it!" is sent in the response.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetIt() {
        String responseMsg = target.path("myresource").request().get(String.class);
        assertEquals("Got it!", responseMsg);
    }
}
```

`pom.xml` - I added the `jersey-media-json-jackson` and the `maven-assembly-plugin` myself, so that you can create a single runnable jar file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.underdog</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-grizzly</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jersey-grizzly</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.underdog.jersey.grizzly.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-archive</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.underdog.jersey.grizzly.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.17</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

With all the above, you can `cd` to the project from the command line and do

1. `mvn clean package`
2. `java -jar target/jersey-grizzly-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

and the application will start.

You can access it from `http://localhost:8080/myapp/myresource`

That's it. Note that the above is a normal jar project. So if you can't follow how to create the archetype, you can pretty much copy everything above into a jar project.

**See Also:**

- [Getting Started with Jersey Using Maven](https://psamsotha.github.io/jersey/2015/10/10/getting-started-with-jersey2.html) for some more explanation.

Comment: If org.glassfish cannot be found, one has to add an explicit dependency on `jersey-container-grizzly-2`: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-grizzly2-http/2.25.1

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment the first answer. So I'm adding a comment here. If you choose to generate the project with the archetype, the command line should be

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.underdog.jersey.grizzly -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.underdog.jersey.grizzly -DarchetypeVersion=2.23.1
```

And not the command line in the [link](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-from-archetype). This will work with the pom provided by peeskillet

Answer (score -3):

Since your using Maven, hence you need to configure the properties to run on the Tomcat.[image: RUN Configuration]

Right click on the Project -> Run as-> Run Configuration 
Select the Maven Tomcat-> change the goals to 'tomcat:run'

Comment: as I said, I actually asked do I have to use tomcat or something like tomcat to use web-services

Comment: of course you need to use tomcat, without the webservice running on the server ,the client cant access it