# Jersey for desktop application

Tags: jersey, gson, rmi

Is it possible to use jersey intead of RMI to build distributed application without using javaEE
Does Gson work for that application?
I only need to use J2SE

Comment: I would suggest to use the JSON binding API instead of Gson: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsonb-api/info

Comment: Jersey is used as the backed of the application. You will need a frontend desktop framework like Swing, JavaFX, or if you know Javascript, you can use [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org). If you use Jersey as the backend, you will also need to use an Http client to make calls to the backend. You can use the Jersey client or any other Http client out there.

Comment: my friend is it pssible to use jersey with javafx for generate http client requests??   @PaulSamsotha

Comment: @JasperdeVries my question is i need only to use j2SE without J2EE

Comment: Jersey is the server. You need a server to serve http requests. You can run Jersey on an embedded server. This is Java SE. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31995589/2587435). Then when you build your desktop application, you will need a http client (such as Jersey Client or [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1322335/2587435)) to make requests to the server.

Comment: thank you my friend i got it  @PaulSamsotha